# Haskell: Confusion over 'foldl' with parenthesized operator (==)

Tags: haskell, equality, fold

Here are a few results of applying 'foldl' to this particular equality operator. I do not understand them - I thought that each line should return true, since "False == False == False ..." is true regardless of the length of the list. I am fairly new to Haskell.

```
Prelude> foldl (==) False [False]
True
Prelude> foldl (==) False [False,False,False]
True
Prelude> foldl (==) False [False,False,False,False]
False
Prelude> foldl (==) False [False,False,False,False,False]
True
Prelude> foldl (==) False [False,False,False,False,False,False]
False
```

I found these results when trying to write a function that tests whether a list of functions give the same result when applied to a common argument (returning a Boolean).

Comment: `==` is a binary operator. When you write `False == False == False`, you’re really writing `(False == False) == False`, which is `True == False`. Perhaps now you can understand what’s happening.

Comment: Of course! Thanks so much.

Comment: If you are familiar with Python, you might have confused this with Python's comparison chaining, where `False == False == ... == False` is, indeed, equivalent to `(False == False) and (False == False) and ... and (False == False)`.

Comment: Yes, and I misunderstood the fold function's bracketing.

Comment: FYI, to check if all the elements are `False`, use `all (==False) [False, False,False]`.

Comment: It's actually telling you if you have an odd number of `False`s in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*== is a binary operator. When you write False == False == False, you’re really writing (False == False) == False, which is True == False. Perhaps now you can understand what’s happening.*

Answer submitted in comments by 'Alexis King'